# How to apply style to first div after h2 in css?

Tags: css

I want to apply the first div color as red. other div as default.

I tried this but not working.

```
.community_team:first-child + div{
  color:red;
}
```

Actual html below

```
<div class="community_team">
<h2>Managers</h2>
 <div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
First Mangaer
 <div>
<div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
2nd Mangaer
 <div>
<div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
3rd Mangaer
 <div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this
.community_team div:first-child  {
  color:red;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `first-of-type` pseudo selector. In the example below, this will match the first `div` element that is a child of `.community_team`.

Also your div elements aren't closed. Change `<div>` to `</div>` to close.

```css
.community_team div:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="community_team">
  <h2>Managers</h2>
  <div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
    First Mangaer
  </div>
  <div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
    2nd Mangaer
  </div>
  <div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
    3rd Mangaer
  </div>
</div>
```

**Also** you can use the adjacent sibling combinator to target the first `div` after the `h2` that is within `.community-team`.  If there should ever be an instance where you may have a `div` *prior* to your `h2` but you still want to target the first div *after* the `h2`.

```css
.community_team h2 + div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="community_team">
  <div>This div is prior to the h2</div>
  <h2>Managers</h2>
  <div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
    First Mangaer
  </div>
  <div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
    2nd Mangaer
  </div>
  <div class="comm_team_item clearfix">
    3rd Mangaer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer acceptable please check it as the "Accepted Answer". This helps not only those that contribute to Stack Overflow, but also those searching for help with similar issues.